# React App - Fetch POST request being received as GET request

Tags: reactjs, express, post, fetch-api

I have RegisterPage.js which is part of my React app containing the following:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function RegisterPage() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  async function register(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    await fetch('http://localhost:4000/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({username,password}),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    });
  }

  return (
    <form className="register" method="post" onSubmit={register}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="username"
        value={username}
        onChange={ev => setUsername(ev.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="password"
        placeholder="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={ev => setPassword(ev.target.value)}
      />
      <button>Register</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default RegisterPage;
```

and I also have index.js as part of my express app which contains the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/register', (req,res) => {
    const {username,password} = req.body;
    res.json({requestData:{username,password}});
});

app.listen(4000);
```

When I am testing this code I am receiving a 'GET' request in my browser so I am receiving a 404 error since there is nothing to 'GET' and I am not sure why this is happening?

I have tried a few approaches I have seen on here before including adding method='post' to my <form />, binding my onSubmit function to the form, specifying content-type, and switching to use axios. I have also made sure to use an incognito window so that there are no extensions interfering with the request. I am receiving no errors other than that the request is not doing what I think it should do.

Is there something I am messing up? Thank you in advance

Edit: Was asked to provide clarification on what I meant when I said "I am receiving a 'GET' request in browser". Included a picture of dev tools on chrome incognito window.
[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

Edit2: Added screenshot demonstrating difference between request send and request received. Also added screenshot of 'GET' request visible with different code for RegisterPage

[image: Contrast between client and api side]

[image: Dev-tools with different code]

Comment: _"When I am testing this code I am receiving a 'GET' request in my browser"_... could you please clarify this? Do you see it in the dev-tools or in the main page area? Any chance you could add a screenshot from the dev-tools _Network_ panel?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this at all ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-butterfly-j3nc43?file=/src/RegisterPage.jsx

Comment: How are you arriving at that URL in your browser? What port is your React app served from? Are you actually starting with your `RegisterPage` component and submitting the form?

Comment: I'm currently following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKs2IZZya7c) where the react app itself is on 3000 and the backend is on 4000. URL is just the endpoint that I specified. I swapped out my RegisterPage code with the one you submitted above and I am still seeing a 'GET' request arriving at the endpoint which i have pictured in my new edit. I start with my rendered component each time and input both fields and press submit.

Comment: I'll ask again, how are you arriving at the `http://localhost:4000/register` URL? Are you just opening that in your browser directly? If so, why?

Comment: I am just opening it up in my browser. As for why, I do not have much of an explanation other than it appeared that's what happened in the tutorial I am following. Kind of a beginner for React and very much so for the backend using express and node so I could be doing something very dumb. Also sorry for taking so long to get back to you it was past 4AM when I was replying to you last night so I had to go to bed @Philisonstrike

Comment: There's no reason to open it in the browser. That represents a GET request for which you have no handler. What are you hoping to see there anyway? The async POST request is done via your `fetch()` call. If you want to view the response, you should use the response from that call (see the sandbox link from earlier for an example)

Comment: Sounds good thank you for taking the time to explain that to me!